# Laravel: error "Undefined variable" when i validate form request with using custom Request class

Tags: php, laravel, validation

In Laravel (5.8) controller, i try to make `update()` function for my `User` model.
I validate data with using my own class `UpdateRequest`. When i put variable `$user` in this class, i have error `Undefined variable: user`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Users;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class UpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'  => 'required|string|alpha_dash|max:255|min:6',
            'email' => ['required',
                        'string',
                        'email',
                        'max:255',
                        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
         ];
    }
}


public function update(User $user, UpdateRequest $request)
    {
        $user->update($request->only(['name', 'email']));
        return redirect()->route('users.index');
    }
```

But if I use `validate` function in controller `update()` method, all works fine.

```
public function update(User $user, Request $request)
    {
     $this->validate($request, [
           'name'  => 'required|string|alpha_dash|max:255|min:6',
           'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,id,' . $user->id,
        ]);

        $user->update($request->only(['name', 'email']));

        return redirect()->route('users.index');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom request class, you don't have the `$user` initialized and you try to use it, while in the controller method the `$user` is passed as a parameter.

**Note** `$this->user` in the Request returns the currently authenticated user, so make sure that you always want to use his ID, instead of an ID of the passed in user, hence the reason I am using `request('user')` to get the user id from the URL.

So try this instead:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
            'name'  => 'required|string|alpha_dash|max:255|min:6',
            'email' => ['required',
                        'string',
                        'email',
                        'max:255',
                        Rule::unique('users')->ignore(request('user'))],
         ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `$user->id` to `$this->user->id` and it should work properly. Check below:

```
return [
            'name'  => 'required|string|alpha_dash|max:255|min:6',
            'email' => ['required',
                        'string',
                        'email',
                        'max:255',
                        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->user->id)],
         ];
```

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

User class instance is missing in UpdateRequest class constructor or you can try with $this->user->id. It may help you.